# Can't use variables in pygame.draw.circle?

Tags: python, variables, floating-point, pygame, draw

When I try to make a shape using variables, I keep getting this error message:

"TypeError: integer argument expected, got float"

```
import pygame._view
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()
```

...

```
barrel = pygame.image.load("images\Barrel.gif")
barrel_create = 0
barrelx = screen.get_height()- barrel.get_height()
barrely = screen.get_width()/2 - barrel.get_width()/2
barrel_exist = 0
explosion_delay = 0
```

...

```
while running:

    if barrel_exist == 0:
        if barrel_create == 500:
            barrely = 200
        barrelx = random.randint(0,400)
        barrel_exist = 1
    if barrel_exist == 1:
        barrely = barrely + 0.1
        if barrely > 400:
            barrel_exist = 0

    if explosion_delay > 0:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (barrelx, barrely), 64, 0)
    explosion_delay = explosion_delay + 1

    if explosion_delay == 100:
    explosion_delay = 0
```

The explosion_delay > 0 when the barrel is "shot".

Comment: In the line following the `if explosion_delay >0:` it looks like you might be missing a function call;  Right now you just have a do-nothing tuple expression statement.  Is that where you're having trouble or is that just a typo?

Comment: (1) The error message should be pretty clear. What's your question? (2) There is no shape creation in your code as far as I can tell. Either add the relevant portion or point out where you're creating a shape.

Comment: I forgot to put in  the pygame.draw.circle() in the post. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`barrely = barrely + 0.1`

`barrely` must be a float at some point because of this line.

I think you should do `pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (int(barrelx), int(barrely)), 64, 0)` to truncate the variables to integers as the function requires.

Comment: int truncates, it doesn't round. Better to define a variant of the round function that returns integer type: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/299459/round-to-nearest-integer

Comment: pygame documentation says floats should be fine: 

'''center (tuple(int or float, int or float) or list(int or float, int or float) or Vector2(int or float, int or float)) -- center point of the circle as a sequence of 2 ints/floats, e.g. (x, y)'''

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which line is giving the error, but if you're using Python 3, `/` gives a `float` result. Use `//` for an integer.

Comment: It doesn't say where there's an error, but I suspect that its where I put the variable instead
of a number. 

Instead of:

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (32,32), 64, 0)

which worked, I used: 

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (barrelx,barrely), 64, 0)

which didn't work. By the way, I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows XP.

Comment: Doesn't say where the error occurred? You didn't get a traceback?

Comment: No. It just showed: pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,255,0),(barrelx,barrely), 64, 0). And below it showed: TypeError: integer argument expected, got float. There were no arrows pointing to a specific place.

Comment: Try inserting some `print` statements to get an idea where it fails and what the values of variables are.

Comment: The values of the variables are all numbers.

Comment: It fails as soon as the program attempts to make the shape.

Answer (score 1):

I change from

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color,(self.x, self.y), 
           self.radius)
```

to

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (int(self.x), 
          int(self.y)), int(self.radius))
```

and it work fine. I use python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers - just wanted to note, that I also bumped in the very same problem, in respect to [PyODE Tutorial 2](http://pyode.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html) (which is done with `pygame`); thanks to the notes in this thread, I modified it so it works, and it's here: [pyode-pygame-example2.py](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/pyode-pygame-example2.py?view=markup).

Note, however, that is *does* matter where you cast to int - if you have a function calculating coordinates, you'd want to "integerize" its return (the 'final' coordinates), not its arguments :) (*mistake I made in the script above*)